# "Understanding the Linux® Virtual Memory Manager" new edition?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, embedded-linux

Is there any new updated version of this classic book planned ?
I'd love to see it being updated to 3.2 or later. It'll make a classic reference with Linux Device Drivers, 4th edition which also is going to be based on 3.2.

Its pain to relate to map old data structures to newer ones while reading this.

Comment: I think I know what "LDD" is, but please update the question with the actual title.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an enquiry toward the author/publisher of a book, not a programming question.